# How to get xml produced from jax-rs?

Tags: java, xml, logging, jax-rs, apache-wink

I would like to log the xml produced from this. How can I do this ?

```
    @GET
    @Path("add")
    @Producse("application/xml")
    public List<String>getCustomerList(....) {


      }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

why i need this is because , I want to have database logging with the request and response header, body etc

Comment: for debug purpose or any other reason?

Comment: I suppose you need method interceptor http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxrs_jcdi_decoratorsandmethod.html

Comment: @RomanVottner i am using wink

Comment: @IshanLiyanage I want to log to database to be get info from later

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by log -- do you mean display on a web page?
So assuming the CustomerList is annotated and the Customer class is also annotated and each has getters and setters.

```
 @GET
 @Path("add")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public Response returnListOfCustomers() {
     CustomerList returnMe = this.getMyCustomerList(); // <-- Made this method up
     return Response.ok(returnMe).build()

  }
```

This is assuming you are trying to create a Restful service: JAX-RS.